# Need assistance designing a 'Find my IPhone'-esque app

Tags: java, android, mobile, geolocation

I am unsure whether this is the place to be asking this kind of question but I need some help in determining if the project I am considering is even possible to accomplish.

See, I have been wanting to make an app on Android Studio that is similar in function to 'Find my IPhone' for IOS - I run a program on my computer, connect to my phone wherever it may be, and get its current location, ideally.

On Wi-Fi, I know this is possible, easily. However, my question is if it is possible to accomplish this while the phone is using mobile data? Is it possible to still connect to the phone, while it is disconnected from Wi-Fi and on mobile data, and get its current location from my PC at home?

I know Find my IPhone can do this so there must be some way. I am completely in the dark as to how mobile data works and how data could be transmitted from it to my PC.

If there is a way, I would love to know as this would open up tons of new possibilities for projects that communicate between my phone and my PC.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I did take a look at that and it does help with the programming aspect, however what I am asking is how I could transmit the location data from my phone, which is using mobile data, to my computer at home? Sorry if its confusing, its hard to put it into words

Comment: Most clients these days are [NATted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), so communication is generally aided by a server, with a public IP (not NATted), that both clients can reach. So, no, you can't get from your phone direct to your home computer, in most cases.

Comment: This is tricky because it's not just a code question, you also need to consider your home network. Depending on how your home network is setup could influence the way the app works. For example, I can access my home network from mobile data, but I had to set up my router to accept the data from an outside source. I'm not sure how to do that programmatically but I would start at looking for network security API's. Just my two cents

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if your app is ready , or you'r asking about how to do it , yes it's possible by getting location (GPS) , but the app is not too easy as you think . you'll need servers , IP , (Learn more about this if you wanna go far with your app) ... but directly from your phone to your home PC , its not possible .